# Stream closed exception in java

Tags: java, exception, stream

Please look at what I have done

```
private InputSource getContent(String fName) throws SAXException, IOException, ServiceException {
        // Some code here
        if(currentNodeRef != null)
        {
            ContentReader reader = contentService.getReader(currentNodeRef,ContentModel.PROP_CONTENT);

            InputStream inputStream = null;
             try 
             {  
                    inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(reader.getContentInputStream(),16384);

                    return new InputSource(inputStream);
             }
             finally
             {
                 if(inputStream!=null)
                    try 
                    {
                        inputStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
             }
        }
        return new InputSource();
}
```

In my parseDocument method I called the above method.

```
parseDocRoot(getContent(fName),path);
```

In parseDocRoot

```
public  void parseDocRoot (InputSource ins, String path) throws SAXException, IOException,
  ParserConfigurationException, ServiceException
  {
          DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
          DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            builder.setEntityResolver(new EntityResolver() {
                public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId)
                        throws SAXException, IOException {
                     return new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[0])); 
                }
            });
        Document doc = builder.parse(ins);
        NodeList list = doc.getChildNodes();
        parseDocument(list,path);
  }
```

I got a error Saying that Stream Not closed and while debugging the above code I found that the error is on the line

```
Document doc = builder.parse(ins);
```

Please help me finding the solution.

Comment: The (first) answer is most probably right, but in general you'd better provide the full stack trace instead of an error description; it makes things easier and avoid confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the error is that the stream *is* closed.  The reason is that you have a finally block:

```
         try 
         {  
                inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(reader.getContentInputStream(),16384);

                return new InputSource(inputStream);
         }
         finally
         {
             if(inputStream!=null)
                try 
                {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
         }
```

You *close* the stream in the finally block.  This code gets executed immediately before returning from the method.  Importantly, the InputStream isn't *consumed* until after the method returns and is processed by the `parse` method.

You should instead put the finally block around the entire block of code -- closing the stream when you are actually done.  The easiest way to do that would be to inline your `getContent` method and put the finally block after calling `parse`.  After you do that, you might be able to figure out a way to encapsulate that logic, but it'll be kind of tricky since you definitely need to keep a handle the the InputStream until you're done parsing so that you can close it.

Another far simpler option would be to  make `getContent` return a `Document` instead by simply moving `parseDocRoot(getContent(fName),path);` inside that method.

Comment: Thanks Kirk. I have tried this out and working. Thanks for your Answer. Will make the changes as you said.

Comment: This answer is correct, however the way you structured your code is probably not ideal, as i'm guessing now you are not closing the stream at all. I'd recommend NOT having a separate method to return the InputSource. I think it's a good practice to try to open and close streams in the same method. (obviously you can call other methods to process the stream).

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy, I believe that's what I suggested.  Particularly my final suggestion to simply return a `Document` -- the idea there is to make `getContent` responsible for both opening and closing the stream.