# Java audio Stream Closed error

Tags: java, audio, ide

I am trying to add sound to a game I am making, but every time I try to load the sound, I get a Stream Closed Exception. I don't understand why this is happening.

**Loads the sound:**

```
public class WavPlayer extends Thread {

/*
 * @param s The path of the wav file.
 * @return The sound data loaded into the WavSound object
 */
public static WavSound loadSound(String s){
    // Get an input stream
    InputStream is = WavPlayer.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(s);
    AudioInputStream audioStream;
    try {
        // Buffer the input stream
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        // Create the audio input stream and audio format
        audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(bis); //!Stream Closed Exception occurs here
        AudioFormat format = audioStream.getFormat();
        // The length of the audio file
        int length = (int) (audioStream.getFrameLength() * format.getFrameSize());
        // The array to store the samples in
        byte[] samples = new byte[length];
        // Read the samples into array to reduce disk access
        // (fast-execution)
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(audioStream);
        dis.readFully(samples);
        // Create a sound container
        WavSound sound = new WavSound(samples, format, (int) audioStream.getFrameLength());
        // Don't start the sound on load
        sound.setState(SoundState.STATE_STOPPED);
        // Create a new player for each sound
        new WavPlayer(sound);
        return sound;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // An error. Mustn't happen
    }
    return null;
}

// Private variables
private WavSound sound = null;

/**
 * Constructs a new player with a sound and with an optional looping
 * 
 * @param s The WavSound object
 */
public WavPlayer(WavSound s) {
    sound = s;
    start();
}

/**
 * Runs the player in a separate thread
 */
@Override
public void run(){
    // Get the byte samples from the container
    byte[] data = sound.getData();
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
    try {
        // Create a line for the required audio format
        SourceDataLine line = null;
        AudioFormat format = sound.getAudioFormat();
        // Calculate the buffer size and create the buffer
        int bufferSize = sound.getLength();
        // System.out.println(bufferSize);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        // Create a new data line to write the samples onto
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);
        line = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        // Open and start playing on the line
        try {
            if (!line.isOpen()) {
                line.open();
            }
            line.start();
        } catch (Exception e){}
        // The total bytes read
        int numBytesRead = 0;
        boolean running = true;
        while (running) {
            // Destroy this player if the sound is destroyed
            if (sound.getState() == SoundState.STATE_DESTROYED) {
                running = false;
                // Release the line and release any resources used
                line.drain();
                line.close();
            }
            // Write the data only if the sound is playing or looping
            if ((sound.getState() == SoundState.STATE_PLAYING)
                    || (sound.getState() == SoundState.STATE_LOOPING)) {
                numBytesRead = is.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                if (numBytesRead != -1) {
                    line.write(buffer, 0, numBytesRead);
                } else {
                    // The samples are ended. So reset the position of the
                    // stream
                    is.reset();
                    // If the sound is not looping, stop it
                    if (sound.getState() == SoundState.STATE_PLAYING) {
                        sound.setState(SoundState.STATE_STOPPED);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // Not playing. so wait for a few moments
                Thread.sleep(Math.min(1000 / Global.FRAMES_PER_SECOND, 10));
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```

**The error message I get is:**  "Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getInIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:134)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:237)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:370)
    at com.sun.media.sound.WaveFileReader.getFMT(WaveFileReader.java:224)
    at com.sun.media.sound.WaveFileReader.getAudioInputStream(WaveFileReader.java:140)
    at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1094)
    at stm.sounds.WavPlayer.loadSound(WavPlayer.java:42)
    at stm.STM.(STM.java:265)
    at stm.STM.main(STM.java:363)"

Comment: The problem is that in your static method `loadSound` you are returning `null` an `Exception` sure is catched and you do nothing

Answer (score 2):

Most probably the file path in this line is not correct:

```
WavPlayer sound1 = WavPlayer.loadSound("coin.wav");
```

You should pass the path of the *'coin.wav'* file instead of just its name.

For instance if its under a folder named sounds, which let's say right under the root of project, that parameter should be '*sounds/coin.wav*'.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your static method `loadSound`. This method returns `null` when an exception is thrown. You catch it but you do nothing with it,

- **NEVER** make empty catch.
- Catch specific exceptions.

I would change your method signature `loadSound` as

```
public static WavSound loadSound(String s) throws Exception // rather than exception specific exception!!
```

And then your method without `try-catch`

Comment: @user2850551 good now you went one step forward! update the question with full stacktrace of the new error!. So more people can help you. See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953142/stream-closed-exception-in-java) help you.